# Convergence for the norm of a sequence in $\ell^{\infty}$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

I still don't know if the statement below is true. It seems to be true but I couldn't find a proof. The statement is the following: for each $n \geq 1$, let $x_n = (a_1(n),a_2(n),\ldots,a_n(n),0,0,\ldots) \in \ell^{\infty}$, where $\ell^{\infty}$ is defined to be the space of all bounded sequences. If for any $1 \leq k \leq n$, $a_k(n) \rightarrow 0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$ then $||x_n||_{\infty} = \sup (a_1(n),a_2(n),\ldots,a_n(n),0,0,\ldots) \rightarrow 0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$? Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 1):

This is not true. Define 
$$a_{k}(n)=\begin{cases}1\text{ if }0\leq n\leq 2k\\ 0\text{ if }n>2k\end{cases}.$$
Then $\|x_{n}\|_{\infty}=1$ for all $n$.

Comment: Also doesn't work. For a fixed $n > 1$, $a_{n-1}(n) = 1$ which does not converge to zero and this is on assumptions.

Comment: @Jerome: No, it is not. The convergence is for a fixed $k$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: Consider $a_k(n):=n\delta_{k,n}$ (this is [Kronecker delta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_delta)).

Comment: In the assumptions, $a_n(n) \rightarrow 0$. In your example, $a_n(n) = n \delta_{n,n} = n$ does not converge to zero.

Comment: @Jerome: No. in the assumptions, for every $k$, you have $a_k(n)\to 0$. In my example, $a_k(n)=0$ for all $n>k$, so in particular, $a_k(n)\to 0$.